Are linear mixed effects model robust to unbalanced clusters?
We have fit the following model:
m = lmer(y ~ time + event + time_since_event + (time|id), data = df)

Some clusters have 1000+ data points, while others have fewer than 10.
Does the lmer model take into account such cluster size imbalances? Are the $p$-values for time, event, and time_since_event reliable even with such imbalances?
Is it necessary to use packages like clubSandwich for clustered robust standard errors:
coef_test(m, vcov = "CR2", cluster = df$id)

The reason we ask is the $p$-values obtained from coef_test fail to support our hypothesis, while those obtained from lmer model do support. Not sure which is correct.

related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/579760/when-are-cluster-robust-standard-errors-a-valid-alternative-to-mixed-models; Abadie, Alberto, Susan Athey, Guido W Imbens, and Jeffrey M Wooldridge. “When Should You Adjust Standard Errors for Clustering?*.” The Quarterly Journal of Economics 138, no. 1 (February 1, 2023): 1–35. https://doi.org/10.1093/qje/qjac038.

Also possibly useful: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1472336-mixed-effects-multilevel-model-vs-cluster-command ... how many clusters do you have?  (Can you edit your question to include the coefficient tables with and without cluster-robust SEs, in a text format?)


Does the lmer model take into account such cluster size imbalances? Are the -values for time, event, and time_since_event reliable even with such imbalances?

Yes: one of the primary reasons to use mixed models is to handle variation in cluster size gracefully.

Is it necessary to use packages like clubSandwich for clustered robust standard errors [?]

Maybe (from a post by Clyde Schechter on the Stata forum):

In situations where you are satisfied that heteroscedasticity and model misspecification are minimal or non-existent, and where observations are independent, or where dependence is fully accounted for with random intercepts, there is no need for vce(cluster). Also, bear in mind that cluster robust standard errors are asymptotically correct. When the number of clusters is small, these can actually be worse than the unclustered standard errors. There is no consensus about how small is small, but I myself would never use vce(cluster) with fewer than 15 clusters, and I might even require a larger number in some circumstances.

(emphasis added). (You can check misspecification, to some degree, by looking at diagnostics like those provided by the DHARMa package or performance::check_model() ...)

If the cluster robust errors are quite different from the non-robust errors, that does suggest that one of those problems is happening. Hard to say which without seeing the two estimates and the number of clusters, though.

I agree. I worry about the possibility that by "fail to support"/"do support" the OP may mean something like p=0.04 with non-robust and p=0.06 with robust errors, in which case they now have a bit of a snooping problem ...
